# HTML code for interlinking php code for getting displaying stored tweets not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter

```
![enter image description here][1]![image of output of twitter_display.php][2]    //htmlsearch.html file
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Twitter</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
window.onload = function() {
// set up the click handler for the form button
var button = document.getElementById("submit");
button.onclick = getTweets;
}

// when you click "Get Tweets" we call this function
function getTweets() {
// set up a new XHR request
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// we're calling search.php and passing in a query string
var url = "twitter_display.php?query=";
var query = document.getElementById("query").value;
if (!query) {
    query = "html5";
}
// we encode the query to handle any special characters properly
url += encodeURIComponent(query);

// this is the function that is called when the XHR request
// to our search.php script is handled, and a response sent back
xhr.onload = function() {
       if (!xhr.status == 200) {

        var errorDiv = document.getElementById("error");
        errorDiv.innerHTML = "Error getting tweets: " + xhr.status;
    }
};
// make the request!
xhr.open("GET", url,true);
xhr.send(null);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Query: <input type="text" id="query">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Get Tweets">
</form>
<div id="error"></div>
<ul></ul>
</body>
</html>


//twitter_display.php file
<?php

// Get constants for tweet display
require_once("twitter_display_config.php");

// Get the HTML structure 
$tweet_page = file_get_contents('tweet_list_template.txt');

// Fill in the most recent individual tweets
$tweet_page = str_replace( '[tweets]',require_once('get_tweet_list.php'), $tweet_page); 

// Fill in the constants and strings needed by site.js after the page loads
$tweet_page = str_replace( '[new_count_refresh]', NEW_COUNT_REFRESH, $tweet_page); 
$tweet_page = str_replace( '[ajax_url]', AJAX_URL, $tweet_page); 
$tweet_page = str_replace( '[more_button]', MORE_BUTTON, $tweet_page); 

// Return the results as HTML
print $tweet_page;
?>

//added new code part for more info i.e get_tweet_list.php
<?php 

require_once('twitter_display_config.php' );
require_once('display_lib.php');
require_once('db_lib.php' ); 
$oDB = new db;

$query = 'SELECT profile_image_url, created_at, screen_name, 
name, tweet_text, tweet_id
FROM tweets ';

// Query string of last=[tweet_id] means that this script was called by site.js
// when the More Tweets button was clicked
if (isset($_GET['last'])) {  
$query .= 'WHERE tweet_id < "' . $_GET['last'] . '" ';
}

$query .= 'ORDER BY tweet_id DESC LIMIT ' . TWEET_DISPLAY_COUNT;
$result = $oDB->select($query);

// Use the text file tweet_template.txt to construct each tweet in the list
$tweet_template = file_get_contents('tweet_template.txt');
$tweet_list = '';
$tweets_found = 0;
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
&&($tweets_found < TWEET_DISPLAY_COUNT)) { 

++$tweets_found; 

// create a fresh copy of the empty template
$current_tweet = $tweet_template;

// Fill in the template with the current tweet
$current_tweet = str_replace( '[profile_image_url]', 
$row['profile_image_url'], $current_tweet);
$current_tweet = str_replace( '[created_at]', 
twitter_time($row['created_at']), $current_tweet);          
$current_tweet = str_replace( '[screen_name]', 
  $row['screen_name'], $current_tweet);  
$current_tweet = str_replace( '[name]', 
$row['name'], $current_tweet);    
$current_tweet = str_replace( '[user_mention_title]', 
USER_MENTION_TITLE . ' ' . $row['screen_name'] . ' (' . $row['name'] . ')', 
$current_tweet);  
$current_tweet = str_replace( '[tweet_display_title]', 
TWEET_DISPLAY_TITLE, $current_tweet);  
$current_tweet = str_replace( '[tweet_text]', 
linkify($row['tweet_text']), $current_tweet);  

// Include each tweet's id so site.js can request older or newer tweets
$current_tweet = str_replace( '[tweet_id]', 
$row['tweet_id'], $current_tweet); 

// Add this tweet to the list
$tweet_list .= $current_tweet;
}

if (!$tweets_found) {
if (isset($_GET['last'])) {
$tweet_list = '<strong>No more tweets found</strong><br />';
} else {
$tweet_list = '<strong>No tweets found</strong><br />'; 
}   
}

if (isset($_GET['last'])) {
// Called by site.js with Ajax, so print HTML to the browser
print $tweet_list;
} else {
// Called by twitter_display.php with require(), so return the value
  return $tweet_list;
}
```

The above code runs individually for twitter_display.php but when i embed it in my html code it does not display the required tweets.
When I fill the text box with some keyword and click on get tweets button it gives an error
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                              htmlsearch1.html:46
 displayTweets                                                         htmlsearch1.html:46
 xhr.onload                                                            htmlsearch1.html:33"
Can you please suggest changes in the code??Do reply please

Go through the new file I have added.Hope it will help you.

Comment: Could you please provide at sample of the output of twitter_display.php

Comment: While waiting for the output of twitter_display.php, you could change `if (!xhr.status == 200) {` to `if (xhr.status != 200) {`

Comment: Also your code does only handle failure requests, there is no handling of successful requests (where xhr.status == 200)

Comment: I have attached a image of output of twitter_display.php.I want to link my first html page to this page for the above shown output.How can I achieve it?I am unaware what code I should give for (xhr.status==200) please suggest

Comment: I don't see any attached screendumps.

Comment: Is the result of twitter_display.php HTML or JSON or something else?

Comment: Okay, then see my suggested answer below

Comment: Thank You so much for your precious time.It is working.Still if I change the keyword in the text box it displays the same tweets it do no get updated as per text box value.How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the result of twitter_display.php is some HTML this would do:

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // set up the click handler for the form button
    var button = document.getElementById("submit");
    button.onclick = getTweets;
}

// when you click "Get Tweets" we call this function
function getTweets() {
    // set up a new XHR request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // we're calling search.php and passing in a query string
    var url = "twitter_display.php?query=";
    var query = document.getElementById("query").value;
    if (!query) {
        query = "html5";
    }
    // we encode the query to handle any special characters properly
    url += encodeURIComponent(query);

    // this is the function that is called when the XHR request
    // to our search.php script is handled, and a response sent back
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            var resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");
            resultDiv.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        } else {
            var errorDiv = document.getElementById("error");
            errorDiv.innerHTML = "Error getting tweets: " + xhr.status;
        }
    };
    // make the request!
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

HTML:

```
<form>Query:
    <input type="text" id="query">
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Get Tweets">
</form>
<div id="error"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

And here is at JSFiddle of it.
http://jsfiddle.net/93ypB/

If the result is JSON, your would have to do some parsing of that in the resonse handling.

Also I would consider added jQuery, as that would make what you are trying to do much easier

**EDIT: Now also including suggestion on how to fix PHP-code:**

Your SQL doesn't include the query, that the problem.
You may need to change the code to something like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT profile_image_url, created_at, screen_name, 
name, tweet_text, tweet_id
FROM tweets WHERE tweet_text LIKE \'%' . $_GET['query'] . '%\' ';

// Query string of last=[tweet_id] means that this script was called by site.js
// when the More Tweets button was clicked
if (isset($_GET['last'])) {  
    $query .= 'AND tweet_id < "' . $_GET['last'] . '" ';
}
```

(The PHP-code changes may contain syntax errors, haven't used PHP for many years)

Comment: Thank You so much for your precious time.It is working.Still if I change the keyword in the text box it displays the same tweets it do no get updated as per text box value.How to resolve this?

Comment: That sounds like a problem with twitter_display.php. I added an alert of url to the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93ypB/1/ which shows that the query is added correct added to the URL

Comment: I need more info on the PHP-code in order to give a suggestion on how to fix that. As fare as I can see from the PHP-code you have provided, there is nowhere that looks at what is in the "query" parameter.

Comment: Sorry ,but i didnt get what you told about JSfiddle.I heared it first time.How is it useful for me?And can u suggest how would I modify twitter_display.php for required results?

Comment: Should I provide any more files which would be useful for u?

Comment: JSFiddle is a place where you can paste HTML + JS + CSS and see it working. This is really good for showing problems and solutions. You see the result in the lower right box, and can try it out from there.

Comment: If you need help with the PHP-code I would need to see more files than what you have provided now

Comment: I have pasted one file of get_tweet_list.php if it is not enough i will send more

Comment: I updated the code as per your suggestion but its giving parse error. "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''; ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\140dev\db\get_tweet_list.php on line 14"

Comment: Sorry my bad... `. '%/' ';` should have been `. '%\' ';`. The answer is updated. But please check my PHP, it's been a while since I wrote some PHP

Comment: lotts of thanx from the bottom of my heart.It worked.You are just simply great.

Comment: well sorry in that case...it left out of my mind...i will keep it in my mind.